# HTML Page with Slider - No Scroll except when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, revolution-slider

I am developing a page with a full screen slider on top (rev slider).
There is an option in the slider that, when clicked, scrolls the page below the slider (where my main content will be).

I don't want the user to be able to scroll at all until that 'button' is clicked to scroll down to the actual content - at which point they can use the mouse just like normal.

Any tips on how this can be achieved would be appreciated.
(NON - WORDPRESS)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question but you can disable html elements using the `disabled` attribute.

To disable an input you can simply add the **disabled** attribute to it: `<input id="myInput" type="text" name="name" disabled>`

Maybe you can use this on your slider and remove the `disabled` attribute with javascript afterwards. Something like this :

```
document.getElementById("myInput").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: I will try to reiterate;  is there a javascript command that allows me to turn off all scrolling - and then with a hyperlink command - turn it back on ?  something that would work on most/all browsers and mobiles.